# Random strings in Python 2.6 (Is this OK?)

Tags: python, random, python-2.6

I've been trying to find a more pythonic way of generating random string in python that can scale as well. Typically, I see something similar to

```
''.join(random.choice(string.letters) for i in xrange(len))
```

It sucks if you want to generate long string.

I've been thinking about random.getrandombits for a while, and figuring out how to convert that to an array of bits, then hex encode that. Using python 2.6 I came across the bitarray object, which isn't documented.  Somehow I got it to work, and it seems really fast.

It generates a 50mil random string on my notebook in just about 3 seconds.

```
def rand1(leng):
    nbits = leng * 6 + 1
    bits = random.getrandbits(nbits)
    uc = u"%0x" % bits
    newlen = int(len(uc) / 2) * 2 # we have to make the string an even length
    ba = bytearray.fromhex(uc[:newlen])
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(ba))[:leng]
```

---

**edit**

heikogerlach pointed out that it was an odd number of characters causing the issue. New code added to make sure it always sent fromhex an even number of hex digits.

Still curious if there's a better way of doing this that's just as fast.

Comment: How do I make this so that it will only include numbers, letters, and underscore? (This includes a dash)

Comment: @wenbert ''.join(random.choice(string.letters+string.digits+"_") for i in xrange(length))

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
import os
random_string = os.urandom(string_length)
```

and if you need url safe string :

```
import os
random_string = os.urandom(string_length).hex()
```

(note random_string length is greatest than string_length in that case)

Comment: Ah! So simple. I didn't think it was cross-platform, but apparently it is.

Comment: Just a followup, it's really odd, but at least on OS X, the getrandbits method is 2-3x faster.

Comment: That's probably because os.urandom will be a cryptographically secure PRNG (usually a stream cipher) while random is a "normal" PRNG which are usually way faster to calculate.

Comment: Is there a way to use this to generate ASCII strings rather than unicode?  For example, so the string can be used in a URL.

Comment: You could use random.choice, string.digits, and string.letters like the first example:
>>> import random, string
>>> ''.join(random.choice(string.letters + string.digits) for i in xrange(10))
'FywhcRLmh1'

(I'm assuming you aren't generating an enormous string like the op since it's for a URL...)

Comment: For URLs one may want to use `string.ascii_letters`.

Comment: @Derek: You can encode the random string in base64 for a url.

Comment: Specifically, I've used this: base64.urlsafe_b64encode(os.urandom(30))

Comment: Sorry for re-posting in an old thread. Is there any way to use `os.urandom(string_length)` and get ASCII letters only? ... As python is an interpreted language, the loop which generates one byte at a time seems quite costly.

Comment: @BiGYaN: jricher gave a solution for that which returns a base64 encoded string, that is: ASCII letters only.

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes a uuid is short enough and if you don't like the dashes you can always.replace('-', '') them

```
from uuid import uuid4

random_string = str(uuid4())
```

If you want it a specific length without dashes

```
random_string_length = 16
str(uuid4()).replace('-', '')[:random_string_length]
```

Comment: or use `uuid4().hex` to get the value without hyphens

Answer (score 6):

Taken from the [1023290](http://bugs.python.org/issue1023290) bug report at Python.org:

```
junk_len = 1024
junk =  (("%%0%dX" % junk_len) % random.getrandbits(junk_len *
8)).decode("hex")
```

Also, see the issues [923643](http://bugs.python.org/issue923643) and [1023290](http://bugs.python.org/issue1023290)

Answer (score 2):

It seems the `fromhex()` method expects an even number of hex digits. Your string is 75 characters long.
Be aware that `something[:-1]` *excludes* the last element! Just use `something[:]`.

Comment: There was a trailing L with the __hex__().  I rewrote the sample code.  Anyways, I think you were right on with it requiring an even number of digits

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the last example, the following fix to make sure the line is even length, whatever the junk_len value:

```
junk_len = 1024
junk =  (("%%0%dX" % (junk_len * 2)) % random.getrandbits(junk_len * 8)).decode("hex")
```