# converting decimal to hex in R

Tags: r

I want to convert a decimal number to hex format in a way that only bit corresponding to that decimal number is set. For example, for input 0, bit 0 should be set and results in

```
>  paste("0x", sprintf("%032x",2^(0)),sep="")  
[1] "0x00000000000000000000000000000001"
```

and for 1, bit one should be set, resulting in

```
>  paste("0x", sprintf("%032x",2^(1)),sep="")  
[1] "0x00000000000000000000000000000002"
```

This works till 30

```
> paste("0x", sprintf("%032x",2^(30)),sep="")  
[1] "0x00000000000000000000000040000000"
```

but does not work for values larger than that

```
>  paste("0x", sprintf("%032x",2^(32)),sep="")  
Error in sprintf("%032x", 2^(32)) :invalid format '%032x'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
```

Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're "overloading" the sprintf function. That is, your type is set to "%032x" and then you pass in the value 2^(32) which the function doesn't see as "%032x" so you get an error.

Here's a couple of semi-related questions, but I don't think these would count as exact duplicates:
[why causes invalid format '%d in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786169/why-causes-invalid-format-d-in-r)

[hex to string formatting conversion in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107331/hex-to-string-formatting-conversion-in-python)

[Why does a 32-bit OS support 4 GB of RAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119278/why-does-a-32-bit-os-support-4-gb-of-ram)